# Java Generic Service in Windows Failover Cluster

Tags: windows, java, failovercluster, windows-service

I created a JAVA-backend in spring boot and configured it as Windows Service. The purpose of the service is to serve REST API.

For instance, to list users, we need to call: localhost:8090/users

I want to make this service available on a Failover Cluster. For that, I created a generic service and it has a new Role IP: 10.143.xx.xx. I was expecting to be able to call now 10.143.xx.xx:8090/users but I'm getting "connection timed out".

Comment: Does netstat on the cluster node hosting the service show it listening on that IP address/port?

Comment: I did telnet 10.143.xx.xx 8090 --> connection refused.
netstat does not show the service IP/Port.

netstat shows the service running on the real IP of the machine and not the Role IP.

Comment: Have you created the Generic Service?  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/creating-and-configuring-a-generic-service-resource/ba-p/371443

Comment: The service is created and is up and running. I can ping it on 10.143.xx.xx which the Role IP. But I expected to be able to navigate to 10.143.xx.xx:8090

Comment: Some may conclude you have not followed the procedure to create the Generic Service.